# Postgres cannot find record by slug, though slug is right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
> p = Publication.find_by(slug: 'xxxx')
nil
> p = Publication.find_by(title: 'XXXX')
....success
> p2 = Publication.find_by(slug: p.slug)
nil
> p2 = Publication.find_by(title: p.title)
...success
> p2.slug == p.slug
true
> Publication.find_by_sql("SELECT  publications.* FROM publications WHERE slug LIKE '%#{p.slug}%'")
...success
```

why?

The database, where issue occurs is running in docker, I have the copy of this database on my computer and there is no issue

I also tried to restart db and it didnt fix the issue

---

psql (10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1))

Comment: What does `Publication.find_by(title: 'XXXX').slug.chars` have to say?

Comment: @muistooshort nothing interesting, its just array of chars. And I cant publish the exact string because  I'm afraid to declassify project.

Comment: `find_by(slug: 'xxxx')` does not translate to `WHERE slug LIKE '%xxxx%'`, but to `WHERE slug = 'xxxx'`. Does `SELECT  publications.* FROM publications WHERE slug = 'xxxx'` return a value?

Comment: Fair enough but there's not much we can do to help you if you can't tell us what's going on. Maybe there is whitespace in the slug that you're not expecting, maybe you have an encoding issue, maybe something completely different is going on.

Comment: @srghma If you're on a development environment you could easily create a test record, and use that in your example. If the issue isn't present on your new record than you might want to check the specific record you're question is about.

Comment: Is it possibly a case sensitivity issue? It seems like slugs should always be lowercase, so that may not be it. Maybe you have an index on the database locally that isn't present in the Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx guys to all of you, as I said I didnt experience this issue on local copy of db, so I resolved this by recreating db

Still don't know the exact cause, something with postgres